# File Not Found error while uploading django project to pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, excel

I'm trying to upload a django project to pythonanywhere free account. The project has a couple of excel files which I need to parse(using the xlrd module)

This is my file map in python anywhere

```
-prvgroups
  -PRVGROUPS
  -***.xlsx
  -***.xlsx
  -***.xlsx
```

django is throwing the following error

```
FileNotFoundError at /
```

I tried to reference the excel file from a CDN but it's still unable to find the excel path

my WSGI file:

```
import os
import sys
#
## assuming your django settings file is at '/home/KjPacino/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
## and your manage.py is is at '/home/KjPacino/mysite/manage.py'
#path = '/home/KjPacino/mysite'
path = '/home/KjPacino/prvgroups'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
#
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'PRVGroups.settings'
#
## then, for django >=1.5:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
## or, for older django <=1.4
#import django.core.handlers.wsgi
#application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHand
```

my settings.py file

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

**edit**

my pythonpath seems to also be pointing in the right direction

```
Python Path:    

['/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/var/www',
 '/home/KjPacino/.virtualenvs/sandbox/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/KjPacino/.virtualenvs/sandbox/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/KjPacino/.virtualenvs/sandbox/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/KjPacino/.virtualenvs/sandbox/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/home/KjPacino/prvgroups']
```

Comment: can you provide more of the traceback from the `FileNotFoundError`?

Comment: a common fix is to use an absolute path instead of a relative path, so, eg `/home/myusername/path/to/my-file.xsls` instead of just `my-file.xlsx`...

Comment: Thank you :) absolute url worked